# Which one of those two queries is faster?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Which of the two following queries might be faster?

```
$cposts = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM posts WHERE company_id = ".$dealid." ");  
$sum_posts= mysql_num_rows($cposts);
echo $sum_posts;
```

or

```
$cposts2 = mysql_query("SELECT count(id) as myid FROM posts WHERE company_id = ".$dealid." ");  
$sum_posts2= mysql_fetch_assoc($cposts2);
echo $sum_posts2['myid'];
```

Comment: ITs the fetch that takes longer in the first query (more rows)  if you dont need the data then dont fetch it (or return it).

Comment: You could try it yourself in about 15 seconds.

Comment: Why not [try it](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_benchmark) yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the count would be better, and will use less processing.

I would go with this:

```
$cposts = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM posts WHERE company_id = ' . $dealid);
$num_posts = (int)mysql_result($cposts, 0);
echo $num_posts;
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Can you please tell me what the `,0` means ?

Comment: And why `*` instead of let's say id

Comment: @asotshia: Because it's faster with *, assuming you don't care about NULL markers.

Comment: the ,0 simply means you're getting the first column returned by your sql query regardless what it's name is. http://www.php.net/mysql-result

Answer (score 1):

SELECT COUNT(id)... is MUCH faster.
The SQL database will do a count and return just that instead of returning all the records and you doing a count on the application side.

Cheers.